# Mock dependent component's dependency with DaggerMock

Tags: android, dagger-2, daggermock

I want to write Espresso tests for an app so I'm trying `DaggerMock` to
mock some external dependencies like local storage.

My `Dagger` setup consists of an `ApplicationComponent` with 3 modules (DatabaseModule, DataModule and ApplicationModule) and for the screen( a `Fragment` ) I want to test I have also another component which depends on `ApplicationComponent`.

What I have tried so far is :

```
@Rule public DaggerMockRule<ApplicationComponent> daggerRule =
        new DaggerMockRule<>(ApplicationComponent.class, new DatabaseModule(), new DataModule(application),
                new ApplicationModule(application)).set(
                component -> {
                    MyApplication app =
                            (MyApplication) InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation()
                                    .getTargetContext()
                                    .getApplicationContext();
                    app.setComponent(component);
                });

@Rule
public final DaggerMockRule<FeedComponent> rule = new DaggerMockRule<>(
        FeedComponent.class, new FeedDataSourceModule(),
        new FeedDownloadImageUseCaseModule(), new FeedServiceModule(), new FeedPresenterModule(null))
        .addComponentDependency(ApplicationComponent.class, new DatabaseModule(), new DataModule(application), new ApplicationModule(application))
        .set(component -> localDataSource = component.localDataSource());

@Mock FeedDao feedDao;

@Mock NetworkUtils networkUtils;

@Mock FeedLocalDataSource localDataSource;
```

where `localDataSource` is actually the dependency I want to mock and it's build in `FeedDataSourceModule` :

```
@Module
public class FeedDataSourceModule {

@Provides
@FragmentScope
public FeedItemMapper providesFeedItemMapper() {
    return new FeedItemMapper();
}

@Provides
@FragmentScope
public FeedLocalDataSource providesFeedLocalDataSource(FeedDao feedDao, FeedRequestDetailsDao detailsDao, FeedItemMapper mapper) {
    return new FeedLocalDataSourceImpl(feedDao, detailsDao, mapper);
}

@Provides
@FragmentScope
public FeedRemoteDataSource providesFeedRemoteDataSource(FeedService feedService, FlagStateService flagStateService,
          @Named("Api-Token") String apiToken, @Named("Screen-Size") String screenSize,
                                                  @Named("Account-Id") String accountId) {
    return new FeedRemoteDataSourceImpl(feedService, flagStateService, apiToken, screenSize, accountId);
}

}
```

and also the `FeedComponent` with the dependency on `ApplicationComponent` :

```
@FragmentScope
@Component( dependencies = ApplicationComponent.class,
        modules = {
            FeedPresenterModule.class,
            FeedServiceModule.class,
            FeedDataSourceModule.class,
            FeedDownloadImageUseCaseModule.class})
public interface FeedComponent {

@Named("Api-Token") String getApiToken();

@Named("Api-Key") String getApiKey();

FeedLocalDataSource localDataSource();

FeedRemoteDataSource remoteDataSource();

void inject(FeedFragment feedFragment);
}
```

With the two `@Rules` I posted above I can confirm that `NetworkUtils` indeed seems to have been mocked correctly since I have used `Mockito.when()` to return `false` value and by using a breakpoint in my code I can see the value is always false :

```
    when(networkUtils.isOnline())
            .thenReturn(false);
```

But this is not true for `localDataSource` which gives me null when I'm calling `localDataSource.getFeedSorted()` although I have declared :

```
    when(localDataSource.getFeedSorted())
            .thenReturn(Flowable.just(feedList));
```

Just in case it helps, this is how I inject the dependencies from `FeedComponent` :

```
            DaggerFeedComponent.builder()
                .applicationComponent(MyApplication.getApplicationComponent())
                .feedPresenterModule(new FeedPresenterModule(this))
                .build()
                .inject(this);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using two DaggerMock rules in a test? I think you can use a single rule like in this [example](https://github.com/fabioCollini/DaggerMock/tree/master/daggermock/src/test/java/it/cosenonjaviste/daggermock/dependency).